# Any image or text added gets in the navigation bar

Tags: html

how do i get the image out of the navigation bar, i have closed all tags opened. image or even text that is entered gets into navigation bar. i have not used css and js, i need to design only with html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title> WheelCart </title>
    <link rel="icon" href="D:\Project1\Resource\favicon.ico" />
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #2ABFEE;
        }
        
        li {
            float: left;
        }
        
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 2px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        li a:hover {
            background-color: #2ABFEE;
        }
    </style>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=""> <img src="D:Project\FinalResource\wheelcart.png" height="50" width="225" </a>
                <div align="center">
                    <li><a href="">  |</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home"> <font size="4"> Home |</font> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home"> <font size="4"> Contact |</font> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home"> <font size="4"> Budget Smart Phones |</font> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home"> <font size="4"> Flagship Devices |</font> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home"> <font size="4"> About |</font> </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                </div? </ul>
</head>

<body>
    <marquee scrollamount="10" direction="left" behavior="scroll">
        <img src="D:Project\FinalResource\ipx.png" />
    </marquee>
</body>
[Image][\[1\]][1]

</html>
```

Comment: There are several bugs in the HTML. `<img src="D:Project\FinalReso` misses `>`. `[Image][\[1\]][1]` is outside `<body>`. What exactly is your question? Maybe you have a problem with float. Add `clear:both` to `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, there were several bugs. I've moved the navbar HTML down to the body tag, and moved the image outside of the list. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dws8mdn4/2/) of the code. This html is barely valid, but restructuring your code is outside the scope of the question.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> WheelCart </title>
  <link rel="icon" href="D:\Project1\Resource\favicon.ico" />
  <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #2ABFEE;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #2ABFEE;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <a href=""> <img src="D:Project\FinalResource\wheelcart.png" height="50" width="225"> </a>
  <ul>
    <li>

      <div align="center">
        <li><a href="">  |</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">
            <font size="4"> Home |</font>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">
            <font size="4"> Contact |</font>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">
            <font size="4"> Budget Smart Phones |</font>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">
            <font size="4"> Flagship Devices |</font>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#home">
            <font size="4"> About |</font>
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <marquee scrollamount="10" direction="left" behavior="scroll">
    <img src="D:Project\FinalResource\ipx.png" />
  </marquee>
</body>
[Image][\[1\]][1]

</html>
```

Comment: Please also note that marquees are [depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee), please don't use them.